# redis-sentinel Docker container can't resolve master instance hostname

Tags: linux, docker, redis, docker-compose, redis-sentinel

I'm trying to set up redis-sentinel from bitnami and I'm getting the following error:

```
redis-sentinel_1  | nami    ERROR Unable to start com.bitnami.redis-sentinel: 
redis-sentinel_1  | *** FATAL CONFIG FILE ERROR ***
redis-sentinel_1  | Reading the configuration file, at line 69
redis-sentinel_1  | >>> 'sentinel monitor mymaster redis 6379 2'
redis-sentinel_1  | Can't resolve master instance hostname.
redis-sentinel_1  | 
andreaskralj_redis-sentinel_1 exited with code 1
```

I tried researching this issue but didn't find much about it. I'm following the steps [here](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-redis-sentinel), and I'm not sure why the error is occuring. For what it's worth, my application works with Redis already, I'm just now trying to get it to work with redis-sentinel. The related code in the development.yml is below:

```
redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    networks:
      - private
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/tmp
  redis-sentinel:
    image: 'bitnami/redis-sentinel:latest'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
    environment:
      - REDIS_MASTER_HOST=redis
    ports:
      - '26379:26379'
    networks:
      - private
```

Please let me know if there is anything else I can post to shed more light on the subject.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wow, really basic reason to why it wasn't working. I just needed the ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes in the redis config, redis-sentinel wasn't loading because redis exited due to not having the password properties configured properly. This was even in the documentation, I just missed it. In case this is helpful to anyone else, the proper config to allow it to work is as follows:

```
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    networks:
      - private
    volumes:
      - ./tmp:/tmp
    environment:
      - ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
  redis-sentinel:
    image: 'bitnami/redis-sentinel:latest'
    depends_on:
      - redis
    environment:
      - REDIS_MASTER_HOST=redis
    ports:
      - '26379:26379'
    networks:
      - private
```